# Error in accessing array content from a class in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hello I have an error when running this script. It uses multi-threading, and has arrays in classes.  For example I am trying to set the array and with `foo1`, and `foo`  do a  `while (gg[50] != 40) do xxxxxx`.

I have a `cout` to Verify that the arrays are set but it returns garbage but when I ask in main it returns correct. Is there a fix for this? or is there a better way of doing this in windows?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */

using namespace std;

class bar {
public:

void setarray(int r, double y){
    gg[r] = y;
}


void foo() {
    int y = 0;
    cout << gg[50] << "gg2" << endl;
    std::cout << "hello from member function2" << std::endl;
    while (gg[50] != 40){
        y++;
    }
    cout << y << " y2" << endl;
}

void foo1() {
    int y = 0;
    std::cout << "hello from member functiondddw1" << std::endl;

    cout << gg[50]<< "gg1"<<endl;
    std::thread(&bar::foo, bar()).detach();

    while (gg[50] != 40){
        y++;
    }
    cout << y << " y1" << endl;

}

double  getarray(int g){
    double ek = gg[g];
    return ek;
}
private:
double gg[80];

};

int main()
{

bar jj;

int u=0;
cout << "which array" << endl;
cin >> u;
double dd=0;
cout << "which number" << endl;
cin >> dd;
    jj.setarray(u, dd);
    if( jj.getarray(u) == 3){
    clock_t tt;
    tt = clock();

    std::thread(&bar::foo1, bar()).detach();
    tt = clock() - tt;

    printf("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n", tt, ((float)tt) /         CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << "done" << endl;
        }
    cout << jj.getarray(50);
     u=0;
    cout << "which array" << endl;
    cin >> u;
 dd=0;
    cout << "which number" << endl;
    cin >> dd;
    jj.setarray(u, dd);

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so not so clear from your description when the cout prints garbage and when it is ok. However, if you refer to cout from the thread, the problem is that main() does not wait until thread finishes and actually exits destroying the Bar jj instance. This is the reason why the garbage may be printed. The rule of best practice - the main should wait for all its threads to finish and only then call a return.

Comment: Thanks for answering I have tried your answer and still nothing.. I am assigning gg[50] in main before I call any threads so the join/detach should not play a part AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with a few rewrites. i added

```
    void main2()
{
    std::thread(&bar::foo1, this).detach();
}
```

and called it from main and added. 
    std::thread(&bar::foo, this).detach();
to the other function.